# How do I reference a field in another class in a separate aspx page, using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, extern

I have a 2D array of doubles in my Default class on my Default.aspx.cs page, like so:

```
protected Double[,] time;
```

By the time the page loads, I have populated this array from a database. Now, I want to reference this array in another file (Diff.aspx.cs) to avoid visiting the database again. Also, the data is used in a read-only fashion.

---

EDIT: There were some helpful links below. I have decided to attempt the hidden querystring/parse method. If anyone has a more straightforward answer, please suggest it. Thanks to everyone who wrote :D

Comment: By "default class", do you mean the code-behind of the first page? If a variable is used by more than one page, it shouldn't be a property of that page. Move it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this time variable, and how do you want to use it in the other page?

Comment: Yes SteveCav, I mean precisely that--the codebehind of the first page. Where would I move it to though, global?

Carlos, I want to read from this array, and use the data to display charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freakishly, I think you are trying to pass values (in your case, array) from one page to another page. You may refer to the link posted by camilin87. There are few ways to do this, like session state, viewstate, querystring, etc. There are pros and cons for each of the options, the most suitable option depends on your situation. You may ask if you need more clarification.

Here's a direct link for you if you are using .NET 4.0.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. I remember using the extern keyword for a data structure once in c++, and everything just kinda "fell into place". It's a pity that this isn't part of C#.

Comment: The extern keyword IS part of C#, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

When you said "I want to reference this array in another file", what file is that? Is it a code-behind file of an aspx page within the same ASP.NET website?

Comment: Okay, I guess I now understand the perils of way too less information. Thanks, guys.

Comment: Read your updated post. Let us know if the querystring method works for you ok :)